# How to use method with parameters in Camel XML DSL?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint

I've got a problem with using method with parameters in Camel XML DSL.

What I've done is something like this:

I've created below bean before my camelContext

```
<bean id="properties" class="java.util.Properties"/>
```

The thing I would like to do is using method 'put' from HashTable, which extends Properties.

When I call a method without parameter it's working perfectly fine.

```
<method ref="properties" method="NAME OF METHOD THAT HAS NO PARAMETERS">
```

or

```
<bean ref="properties" method="SAME AS ABOVE"/>
```

Method that I'm trying to use:

```
public synchronized V put(K key, V value)
```

But when I'm trying to use something like the code below I would like to assign some parameters
I've tried a lot of possibilities, maybe it's impossible or my knowledge of syntax is poor:

```
<method ref="properties" method="put" argument="key_el" arugment="val_el"/>

<method ref="properties" method="put" value="key_el" value="val_el"/>

<method ref="properties" method="put?keyEl&valEl"/>

<method ref="properties" method="put">
  <argument id="key" value="someKey" type="java.lang.String"/>
  <argument id="value" value="someValue" type="java.lang.String"/>
</method>
```

There's plenty more that I've tired, some of them are just not worth of showing. I read from people apache and camel documentation, that there's possibility to make it somehow but there was no example of doing that in XML DSL.

Thanks in advance for any hints and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call beans method with arguments using `method="put('key', 'value')"`. You can also use simple syntax there if you need values from the Exchange like body, headers or exchange properties `method="put('bodyValue', ${body})"``

This approach also works with simple language. Say if you have object stored in to message header you can call it's methods using ${headers.helloBean.hello('Tim')}

```xml
<bean id="ExampleProperties" class="java.util.Properties" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="testRoute">
        <from uri="direct:testRoute" />
        <bean ref="ExampleProperties" method="put('bodyValue', ${body})" />
        <setBody>
            <simple>${bean:ExampleProperties?method=get('bodyValue')}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <log message="Body value: ${body}" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Be careful when storing values to beans instead of using body, headers or exchange properties as beans persist between exchanges.

Comment: Sorry for not reacting for your answer, it worked for me well. I got another issues related with creating a bean with parameter. I've tried like:


```<bean id ="someClassWithConstructorArgument" class="java.lang.SomeClassWithConstructorArgument">
<constructor-arg value="sth"/>
</bean>```

Do not sure what's wrong with that one.

Comment: I am guessing that you've incorrect package there as `java.lang` package is part of the java standard library. Other than that that looks fine to me provided that the class has public constructor that accepts String as an argument.

Comment: Ok maybe I gave a bad example of my problem. I'm not able to create an instance of a class without null constructor. What I was trying to show was some approach that I've tried. For example:

```<bean id="booleanExample" class="java.lang.Boolean">
     <constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>```
Boolean got 2 types of constructor with boolean or with a String If I'm not mistaken. How Can I use one of those or what kind of syntax I should use.

Comment: Since you're using OSGi blueprints instead of Spring-XML you can try using `<bean id="booleanExample" class="java.lang.Boolean"><argument value="true" /></bean>`.